# Deleting texts with javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to remove some changing texts using javascript.
I know hwo to remove static text but,

Example text like:  **Year2012 Mon2 Day18**

```
title.replace("Year2012 Mon2 Day18", "");
```

The date will change so how do I remove it if its variable (like date)?

Comment: Look at `regex`. It can be used to match those dates.

Comment: This is javascript and not jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regex:

```
title = title.replace(/Year\d{4}\sMon\d{1,2}\sDay\d{1,2}/, '');
```

Comment: It would appear that `title` is a string, so `innerHTML` wouldn't help, the 2nd looks good though.